# How to check if the file encrypted with correct encrypted mode using SQLCipher?

Tags: sqlcipher-android

The SQLCipher library uses AES/CBC encryption by default whereas I want to encrypt the data base with AES/CFB encryption with no padding. I have used below statement to change the mode encryptedDB.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA cipher = 'aes-256-cfb';");

Now, How can I verify it is encrypted correctly with this mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the command to find out the cipher mode but this support is removed since version 4.0.0.

```
> PRAGMA 'your_key'; 
> PRAGMA cipher;
```